# Analyze a growing heap during load

Tags: java, performance, jboss, profiler

My jboss AS5 application is suffering from a weird heap behavior during "peak hour" load. It's constantly growing until it has so little free space to work with that it fails to process new requests.

This would be normal if we were talking about a typical leak, however I've ruled this out by simply lowering the load right before it goes over the threshold where it's not able to process new requests and then - after a cool-down period - restarting another "peak hour". The application (VM) is then able to process the high load as if nothing had happened.

How do I approach this problem? I've tried trial and error (heap sizes, GC, proprietary profiling/timing log) and I've tried hooking up jprofiler but no data of value has been presented to me.

Is there a good way to find out which objects (class) are constantly growing over time? I'm talking around ~200mb/hour.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to see heap growth using any of the below tools,

1. Utilities like JVisualVM,jstat (very little overhead)
2. Profilers like Jprofiler (considerable overhead)

both type of tools should show objects which are taking more heap space and if you continuously monitor the heap growth then you can also find out which objects are growing over period of time.

If you still think these tools are not showing valuable data then go for old fashioned way.

1. Take heap dumps of your heap regularly after an interval of time. Interval of time should be selected in such way that you get enough number of heap dumps to analyze and should be minimal
2. Feed those dumps to heap analyzer tools and see the trend for objects growing over period.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This helped a lot. I actually did take on this idea from another source yesterday and used jmap dumps to figure out what's growing and growing. It turned out to be jboss cache related - now I just need to figure out why =).
Still a bit disappointed that jprofiler didn't really help be to build and analyze a histogram.